# How to add a emoji regex validation in JS?

Tags: regex, emoji, parsley.js

I need to add emoji regex validation on my forms. I use parsley JS for regex matter, currently my input first-name has this regex:

```
^[^`~!+,!@#$%^&*();\/|<>"0-9=\[\]\{\}\_☺]{1,255}$
```

And I found this regex for emoji:

```
/(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])/g
```

The question is how to combine these two regex? I tried several syntax but no success so far.

Comment: Try [this one](https://regex101.com/r/P7X4YR/1).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew :) that work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest

```
^(?:(?!(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff]))[^`~!+,!@#$%^&*();\/|<>"0-9=[\]{}_☺]){1,255}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P7X4YR/1)

The structure of the pattern is:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group that wraps a specific pattern matching...

  - `(?!<HERE_GOES_EMOJI_PATTERN>)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is an enmoji
  - `` [^`~!+,!@#$%^&*();/|<>"0-9=[]{}_☺] `` - any char other than the one defined in the character class
- `){1,255}` -... 1 to 255 consecutive occurrences
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 4):

In JS, now you can use:

`.match(/\p{Emoji}/gu);`

or:

`.match(/(\p{Emoji_Presentation}|\p{Extended_Pictographic})/gu)`

To see which characters match each see [this link to the unicode emoji data](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/emoji/emoji-data.txt)